# Crash while new[] in tinyxml2 in android

Tags: c++, crash, operator-keyword

I am looking into the CPP code which i am not very familiar with and facing a crash while assigning a constant simple string in tinyxml2. I have searched for 2 days and could not find any logic for this over the net.
This issue is hardly reproducible.

crash:

```
pid: 22847, tid: 22967, name: BluetoothAdapte  >>> com.android.bluetooth <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
    r0 ab425974  r1 e4cf3de5  r2 80000000  r3 ab3f26d8
    r4 ab425b00  r5 0000344e  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
    r8 00000000  r9 ab425bb8  sl 00000004  fp 00000002
    ip a0000000  sp e4bd46c8  lr 00000000  pc 00000000  cpsr 800f0010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000  <unknown>

stack:
         e4bd4688  01000000  
         e4bd468c  f722fc4d  /system/lib/libstdc++.so (operator new[](unsigned int)+8)
         e4bd4690  ab3f26d8  [heap]
         e4bd4694  e4ce76af  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (tinyxml2::StrPair::SetStr(char const*, int)+40)
         e4bd4698  ab425974  [heap]
         e4bd469c  ab425bd0  [heap]
         e4bd46a0  ab425950  [heap]
         e4bd46a4  e4cf3de0  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so
         e4bd46a8  e4d3ed20  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so
         e4bd46ac  e4ce895b  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (tinyxml2::XMLElement::FindOrCreateAttribute(char const*)+106)
```

code :

https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/blob/master/tinyxml2.cpp: crashes at line 177

```
void StrPair::Reset()
{
    if ( flags & NEEDS_DELETE ) {
        delete [] start;
    }
    flags = 0;
    start = 0;
    end = 0;
}


void StrPair::SetStr( const char* str, int flags )
{
    Reset();
    size_t len = strlen( str );
    start = new char[ len+1 ];          //crashes here
    memcpy( start, str, len+1 );
    end = start + len;
    this->flags = flags | NEEDS_DELETE;
}
```

Comment: well your code is not minimal enough (parts are missing and for this reason not repdocuible)

possible problems:
what is the type of start?
have you checked the value which strlen returns (you have to add that ;))
is there a reason not to use containers of the STL like vectors,lists,...?

Comment: @mbed_dev, type of start is char*, strlen returns size_t only(bionic lib). I am passing constant string only: "TAG" and FLAG is 0. I can not

Comment: use STL since this is all open source.